# How to get the age of a nodes in kubernetes via prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, nodes, prometheus, grafana

I would like to get the age of a node in my kubernetes cluster via a query to prometheus in K8s like in the `kubectl get nodes` we got an age info.

How to access this info?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you need the uptime of the node or the age itself?

Comment: I could use both, but i am looking for the uptime actually

Answer (score 1):

If you need the uptime of the node (that is what the `Age` for the K8s resources generally denotes IIUC), you can use the `node_boot_time_seconds` metric that comes after installing the `Node Exporter` with Prometheus.

You can follow this guide to install Node Exporter for your cluster: https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/node-exporter/

Comment: Hi, this seems like the good request, however I am not sure to understand what is the unit of the value, it seems to be seconds according to the name of the query but if I do the conversion in days I get Thousands of days and my nodes are 10 days aged according to kubernetes.

By the way, what is the difference withtthe query kube_node_created ?